# How do I use a string to show Data in AutoSuggestBox in UWP

Tags: c#, api, uwp, suggestbox

I am trying to to use an AutoSuggestBox to Display the Data as being typed from a string.

I have tried making an array with some words that will be shown in the AutoSuggestBox as the user types, I however need the Data from the API which is being stored in a string to show in the AutoSuggestBox. For now, I am using an array to show 3 words as the user types, and the string that contains the API data, being added into a ListBox.

This however is being done in the AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged method, so as the user types, the data that we get gets added to the ListBox.

```
private async void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            string[] Autoitems = new string[] { "check", "apple", "banana" } //Temporary Array for AutoSuggestBox

            var Auto = (AutoSuggestBox)sender;
            var Suggestion = Autoitems.Where(p => p.StartsWith(Auto.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
            Auto.ItemsSource = Suggestion; //This displays only items from array as being typed.

            string searchedName = SearchBox.Text;

            myFood = await NutritionixAPI.GetFood(searchedName);

            //The data I get from the API is stored in the temp string
            string temp = myFood.hits[0].fields.item_name + " Calories: " + myFood.hits[0].fields.nf_calories + " Protein: " + myFood.hits[0].fields.nf_protein + " Fat: " + myFood.hits[0].fields.nf_total_fat;
            ResultListBox.Items.Add(temp); //temp string data is added to a listbox

            Total += myFood.hits[0].fields.nf_calories;
            TotalCalories.Text = ((int)Total).ToString(); //Adds the calories of each added food to the Total Variable and Display it
        }
```

I expect the AutoSuggestBox to show me the Data from the string as being typed. For Example "Bana" - List of food pop up with the name Bana.

[image]

But the actual result is the AutoSuggestBox showing the ArrayData and the API Data in string being added into the ListBox as being typed.

Comment: *For Example "Bana" - List of food pop up with the name Bana*, I'm not really understand this mean. could you tell more detail about this.

Comment: So its a food library, which has a list of food. And full word "Banana" If you start with B and slowly type all the way to Banana, A list needs to pop up. But all in the auto suggest box. Right now it does this in a list. Heres the results [Result Image](http://prntscr.com/nij3ls) . I want the list to be in where the first arrow is, not the 2nd arrow.

Comment: Which arrow you want to realize left arrow or down arrow?

Comment: I want the contents from the bottom arrow to show in the left arrow.
So Bana Krisp Fruit Crackers Calories: 150 Protein to be showed in textbox where (Banana) is first arrow to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the contents from the bottom arrow to show in the left arrow. So Bana Krisp Fruit Crackers Calories: 150 Protein to be showed in textbox where (Banana) is first arrow to the left.

For your requirement, you could get typed data with `NutritionixAPI` then converter the data to format string. Create a new list for AutoSuggestBox Itemsource that stored the format string.

```
private async void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    switch (args.Reason)
    {
        case AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.ProgrammaticChange:
        case AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.SuggestionChosen:
            sender.ItemsSource = null;
            return;
    }
    var query = sender.Text;
    var hits = await NutritionixAPI.GetFoods(query);
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    foreach (var hit in hits)
    {
        string temp = hit.fields.item_name + " Calories: " + hit.fields.nf_serving_size_qty + " Protein: " + hit.fields.nf_serving_size_unit + " Fat: " + hit.fields.item_id;
        if (items.Exists(p => p == temp) == false)
        {
            items.Add(temp);
        }

    }
    var Suggestion = items.Where(p => p.StartsWith(sender.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
    sender.ItemsSource = Suggestion;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! I am however coming up with a little issue. https://i.imgur.com/pfqctl7.png and it is leading to my RootObject method in my API Class https://i.imgur.com/dL8NMgu.png If you need more info on my API Class, I can screenshot the whole thing if that makes things easier. Thanks anyways for helping so much even upto this point! Legend!

Comment: I implemented  `NutritionixAPI` with Nutritionix v1.0.  And there many different fields, You could replace it with your own model class.

Comment: Yes but I dont think the error is in with fields, it is to do something with the Enums (GetEnumerator) - Even when nothing is in the foreach statement, hits still shows error : https://i.imgur.com/x3tkxzH.png --------------


https://i.imgur.com/16glry4.png : This is my NutritionixAPI class, am I missing something? Sorry for this.

Comment: I have got it working, just needed to name the hits field in my method so hits.hits and it all worked. Thank you so much for helping with this!